# MongoDB connection error nodejs express mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dotenv

im a beginner and trying to test some basic conection to MongoDB with node and express and mongoose and cannot find why is returning as undifined

Im using a dotenv module to use an env variable, any advice

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()`
or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

This is my code

```
// index.js

import app from './app'
import './database'

app.listen(app.get('port'))
console.log('Greetings from express')
```

```
// database.js

import mongoose from "mongoose";
import config from './config'

(async () => {
    const db = await mongoose.connect(config.mongodbURL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log('Database connected to:', db.connection.name);
})();
```

```
// config.js
import { config } from "dotenv";
config();

export default {
    mongodbURL: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
};
```

```
// .env
MONGODB_URI = mongodb://localhost/tasksapi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't amending your config files, then you may not have to have your `config.js` file, you could simply call `config()` in index.js, and any files loaded after it will have access to `process.env`.

In that case, your code would look as follows:

```js
// index.js

import {config} from 'dotenv'
config()

import app from './app'
import './database'

app.listen(app.get('port'))
console.log('Greetings from express')
```

```js
// database.js

import mongoose from "mongoose";
import config from './config'

(async () => {
    const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log('Database connected to:', db.connection.name);
})();
```

Alternatively, if you wish to keep your `config.js`, then calling dotenv's `config()` in `index.js` would also ensure that your envvars are loaded by the time the config.js exports them.

Comment: Hey there, thank you, it totally makes sense, even as @Kandonga said, but ill try and got same error if i change to a string  `const db = await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tasksapi'` got an MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: If you're geting ECONNREFUSED and the URI is okay, then it must be related to your MongoDB Config - Do you have mongodb running locally, set up for authentication-free login etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you are doing here

```
await mongoose.connect(config.mongodbURL,
```

change it to `await mongoose.connect(process.env.mongodbURL,`

and store the mongodb url in you config.env file like so

```
mongodbURL=mongodb+srv://USERNAME:<PASSWORD>@cluster<CLUST>/<DBNAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

, that will work for you